# Write PrivateRoute Component in a typescript friendly way

Tags: typescript, react-router-v4

I am learning to use React Router in Typescript. I am also reading this article on how to implement PrivateRoutes in typescript+react router.

https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

The blog above has a code segment to implement the PrivateRoute as

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
   <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      isLoggedIn.isAuthenticated === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/login' />
   )} />
)
```

However my typescript compiler doesn't like the above code

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Main.tsx:19:35
    TS7031: Binding element 'Component' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
```

How can I modify this code above so that it becomes typescript friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code to mimic a Route:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }: RouteProps) => {
  if (!component) {
    throw Error("component is undefined");
  }

  const Component = component; // JSX Elements have to be uppercase.
  const render = (props: RouteComponentProps<any>): React.ReactNode => {
    if (fakeAuth.isAuthenticated) {
      return <Component {...props} />;
    }
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
  };

  return (<Route {...rest} render={render} />);
}
```

The original definition of Route is `Route<T extends RouteProps = RouteProps> extends React.Component<T, any>`, but with Typescript 2.9 there is currently no way to use the spread operator in the first line with generics, thats why the general RouteProps type is used.

Answer (score 10):

There is a Typescript syntax for [renaming destructured properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#property-renaming).

In building a private route, it looks like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}: {component: any}) => (
    ...
)
```